# org.apache.commons.net.ftp UPLOAD

Tags: upload, ftp

Estou fazendo um upload de um arquivo para o servidor porem se o arquivo for um pouco grande (200mb +) o upload é finalizado mas o programa trava e não me da um retorno se completou o upload. Se o arquivo for menor não tenho esse tipo de problema. Segue como estou fazendo:

```
            ftp.login(usuario, senha);
            ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            arquivo = new File(file);
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(arquivo.getAbsolutePath());

            // TRAVANDO AQUI MAS O ARQUIVO É ENVIADO
            boolean retorno = ftp.storeFile("/" + usuario + "/" + arquivo.getName(), is); 

            if (retorno) {
                 //faz algo
            }else{
                //faz algo
            }
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Galera dando -1 no post mas não da uma opinião!? É assim mesmo? Ficou alguma duvida na minha pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu prolema.

Para registro achei a solução neste post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530240/commons-ftpclient-hangs-after-uploading-large-a-file